# Save an animated gif from an actionscripted animation

Tags: actionscript, graphics, animation, gif

Is it possible to save a .fla file as an animated gif from an actionscripted animation? I know you can do it from a tweened animation quite easily, but haven't been able to figure out a way to do it from a scripted one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question.

If you want to write an actionscript animation to a file from the Flash IDE, you can try quicktime(.mov) by choosing:
File > Export Movie and choosing QuickTime as the output format. This will allow you save the rendering of your actionscript to a file. A handy video by Lee Brimlow is available [here](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play?id=89).

I don't think it's possible to save a gif from the IDE for actionscript, but if GIF is a must you can try rendering with actionscript into an array of BitmapData objects that you would feed to a GIFEncoder.

Have a look at this fun and easy to use [GIF Encoder by Thibault Imbert](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=93). I found it really easy to get started with.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still curious, check [Converting SWF into GIF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351305/converting-swf-into-gif-file/6351313)