# Converting SWF into GIF file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash file where I load a remote SWF file into my own. Now what I want to do is convert that remote SWF file into a GIF that I can save onto my server.

The remote file is a SWF that has a variable amount of frames, and I somehow need to be able to figure out the amount of frames (I presume), and take a snapshot (picture) of every frame, to turn the taken pictures into a GIF file. That's what I THINK has to be done, however I have no idea if it's even possible to take pictures/snapshots of remote SWF files.

I need some serious suggestions on how I could get this working. I'm a serious Flash newbie, and anything would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trying to capture stage area using BitmapData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450381/trying-to-capture-stage-area-using-bitmapdata/2450454#2450454)

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
bmd.draw(stage);
```

And this should help you creating the animated GIF:
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=93

Comment: Would this work the same when the remote swf has been loaded as a MovieClip?

Comment: haven't tried it, but i suppose it should work. you should put the movieclip to the stage and iterate through the frames, taking one snapshot for each of those frames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the totalFrames property to see how many frames there are and loop through them. You can draw the frames into a BitmapData object.